# Wiley article doesn't recognise natbib citations and reference list

Tags: pdftex, citing, natbib, wiley-article

I have a latex file "main.tex" as follows:

```
\documentclass[alpha-refs]{wiley-article}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{natbib}

\begin{document}

\section{Document class options}

\citep{urmson2008autonomous,lees2010theoretical} and \citep{geiger2012we}.

\bibliography{sample}

\end{document}
```

When I compile this via the terminal as `pdflatex main.tex`

It doesn't recognise the citations and does not produce a reference list:
[image]

The natbib error messages are:

```
Package natbib Warning: Citation `urmson2008autonomous' on page 1 undefined on 
input line 10.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `lees2010theoretical' on page 1 undefined on i
nput line 10.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `geiger2012we' on page 1 undefined on input li
ne 10.
```

I haven't included the bib file `sample.bib`, because it does this with all references regardless.

pdflatex version:
`pdflatex --version` -> `MiKTeX-pdfTeX 4.6.1 (MiKTeX 21.6)`

Obviously, to compile the `wiley-article.cls` is needed. I have:

```
% wiley-article.cls, v1.5, 2018/07/05
% Developed by Overleaf.
```

Thank you!

Comment: you must call bibtex too.

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/35864 for why you need to run BibTeX and hints on how to do it.